Coldfusion secure login and session methods
I'd like to implement secure authentication for a Lucee CFML application, but the example I found below requires a big learning curve to follow along. Any recommendations for creating a secure session that's more intro level, but still considered a best practice?
https://github.com/ddspringle/framework-one-secure-auth

That example uses a bare bones fw/1 MVC application to showcase how to implement the security features, but I understand it can be a bit overwhelming since I threw everything including the kitchen sink into it lol
You can get the information you need to build secure CFML authentication and session management by following the guides available at https://cfdocs.org/security - scroll to the bottom under the heading 'Code Security' and you'll see sections for authentication and session management. The principles are spelled out a little better there than in the fw/1 example, tho they are meant to go hand in hand - the cfdocs give you a broader understanding of what the fw/1 code is doing for authentication and session management. That said, this method can be used with any CFML application and any (or no) framework, fw/1 was just a handy vehicle to demonstrate the method usage at the time I wrote it.
HTH
-- Denny

Look at the ColdBox framework for CFML.
Very easy to learn and has a lot of built-in functionality including a security module for login/auth/permissions.
Once you get a fundamental understanding, it is going to make your development 100% easier and faster.
Kevin
